# Foja theme not uploading correctly on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

I am trying to upload Foja theme using the zip file that I have foja.zip. However, it is not uploading correctly. Can someone help me out with the problem, kindly?

This is how the theme appears after uploading on the website.

[image: Look of the theme after uploading]

This is the full zip folder which I downloaded. Picture attached below.
[image: Downloaded Zip folder]

And these are the three files which appear after extracting the zip folder. And I tried uploading foja.zip and foja-child.zip. However, it's not working.
[image: Three zip files after extraction of the zip folder]

Can someone let me know what issue I am having? The version I am using right now is 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

I actually didn't activate the plugins which were required for the Foja theme due to which the website was not displaying any content.
It is working fine now.